# ASP.net MVC Performance Implication of having large variable names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, webserver

While It is ideal to avoid Large Variable names, small ones do not capture the essense of maintainability.

Where is the tradeoff between variable sizing on a typical IIS/ASP.Net Setup with code readability, maintainability & understandability.

Comment: When your code is compiled, your variable names don't matter. Because they're never saved as you declared. Why do you concern about it?

Comment: In addition to what @nevra said, the only difference between a long variable and short variable is that your actual *.cs file size may be larger.  The variable names that you use only exist when you are editing the code.  have a look at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9025225/130387) - you can see the variable names `foo` and `bar` and nowhere in the compiled c# output (IL)

Comment: this is more a naming conventions related issue, highlighted by a static code analyzer.

Comment: Which static analysis tool are you using?   Not doubting you at all, but VS doesn't mention anything about long variable names in their error list and I have never seen ReSharper complain either (one could argue R# is not a true static analysis I suppose).  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2010/03/23/comparison-of-code-analysis-warnings-and-errors-visual-studio-2008-versus-visual-studio-2010/  If you could point out the specific static analysis message/platform, there could be more of a reason for the message you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

As nevra said....

Variable name lengths have absolutely no impact on run time performance because they simply are not part of the runtime code.